# Tracking http requests sent by the browser using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, httprequest

Using javascript or jquery, is there a way to track the http requests(including headers, parameters, etc.), sent by a webpage? What I want to achieve is something similar to the functionality of the 'network' tab of Google Chrome's developer console. All the solutions I found was either tracking Ajax requests or requests made using javascript(using XMLHttpRequest Object). This functionality should also be cross browser compatible.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network

Comment: As an extension or as code running in the browser? Code running in the browser is not going to have access to it.

Comment: You can check the request into your browser using console please 
Press  F12 Key and click on the Network tab. now reload page you can see all the request and response. and once ajax will fire you can also see the ajax request and response.

Comment: Actually what I want is just a javascript function to do this. Not an extension. I need to track the requests sent only by the website which contains this javascript file.

Comment: @tibzon Check out my 1st and 3rd way!

Comment: Similar question: [JS/web debugger to trace origins of HTTP requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315365/js-web-debugger-to-trace-origins-of-http-requests)

Comment: @Mitul actually what I want is to do the exact thing programmatically I need to keep track of all the requests and store them locally.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thank you for the response. I will have a look at the 1st solution and will try.

Comment: For that you need to create the browser extension

Answer (score 2):

You have three choices.

1. Make sure you know all the places where a request can get fired, and attach an event to it, say `RequestFired`. And bind the `onRequestFired` event in your JavaScript / jQuery code.
2. Go through the Network Developers document or each browser and based on the browser, execute it. This feature may not be available in older browsers like Internet Explorer 7 and 8.

   - [Google Developers Doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network)
   - [Firefox Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API)
   - [NetworkInformation.connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/connection)
3. If it is for a particular server, read the Server Log using a server side script and access it using an endpoint. You can use long polling method and fetch the contents of the log, may be this way:

   ```js
       // jQuery
       $(document).ready(function () {
         setInterval (function () {
           $("#log").load("/path/to/endpoint.log");
         }, 5000);
       });
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <h3>Logs</h3>
       <div id="log"></div>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can't track everything.

For example some of the calls in Xmlhttprequest are transparent (301 HTTP codes) and can't be handle by javascript client side.

see the XMLHTTrequest specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#infrastructure-for-the-send-method

This among a few other reasons. if you want to track the requests of a "webpage" it's better to use the development tools of that browser or packet capturing.

On the userExperience side you can only do very limited things.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, if you are implementing a single page web-application with a framework like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). There you can do that using HTTP [interceptors](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/).

Other than that, you can only track Ajax requests, but not JavaScript requests.